# mysql & select into OUTFILE - writing binary data to file

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which has column of type binary.

```
---------------+---------+----------+-------------+
| appid | imei             | request_timestamp | city_id | state_id | country_id  |
+-------+------------------+-------------------+---------+----------+------------+-----------+
| 45861 | 101111000110     |        1327119595 |     700 |       43 |          5      |
| 93502 | 1000011001010    |        1327119595 |     305 |      490 |          9 |      |
+-------+------------------+-------------------+---------+----------+------------+-------

SELECT * INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED
 BY '\n'  FROM log_track_tbl_382 ,the csv file has data in the form 

45861,"101111000110\0\0\0\0",1327119595,700,43,5
93502,"1000011001010\0\0\0",1327119595,305,490,9
```

The binary column is not written to txt file in proper format.
Can any one suggest what should be the proper mysql command to preserve binary data in the file .
When i run this command from mysql prompt

Comment: Please fix this formatting atrocity. If it is too big to fit on the screen, then it is probably too big to be included. Simplify your example down to the minimal case that exemplifies the issue. (It may help with your own debugging as well!)

Comment: Please define what "not proper format" means. What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: Binary present data mysql is not the same in text file.Column value present in table is 101111000110  and in the text file its like 101111000110\0\0\0\0.

Comment: I want value in text file to be same as in table.I am trying infobright community edition and this edition doesnt support mysql inserts and data can be loaded only via  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE .

Comment: select into outfile is going to dump exactly what's in the fields. if you get a `\0` in the output, that means there's an ascii null/0 character in the field. The dump is working as expected, the nulls are simply not shown in the monitor output.

Answer (score 5):

Try to Use `DUMPFILE` in place of `OUTFILE`.

Selecting this option over `OUTFILE` results in the query results being written as a single line, omitting column or line terminations. This is useful when exporting binary data such as a graphic or a Word file. Keep in mind that you cannot choose `OUTFILE` when exporting a binary file, or the file will be corrupted.

Hote that a `DUMPFILE` query must target a single row; combining output from two binary files doesn’t make any sense, and an error will be returned if you attempt it.

Comment: The outfile doesn't even work for me with normal text, let alone binary, there's \ characters everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

To export, you can encode binary columns:

```
SELECT appid, to_base64(imei), request_timestamp, city_id, state_id, country_id
FROM some_table
INTO OUTFILE 'test.txt' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM log_track_tbl_382
```

Then to import, you will have to decode the binary data

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'test.txt' INTO TABLE some_table;

UPDATE some_table SET imei = from_base64(imei);
```

Of course, if you have bad data to begin with, you need to know exactly what is bad and how to undo the operation that made it bad.